# Сохранение загруженного файла

Tags: файлы, php

Не могу сохранить файл, постоянно получаю ошибку

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/down/666-1680x1050.jpg) function.move-uploaded-file: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/tanki_yrg/data/www/tankist10.hosting-test.org.ua/file.php on line 6
```

при

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'],"/down/".basename($_FILES['cover']['name']));
```

*copy()* тоже не работает
Почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Папка загрузок
$uploadsDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';

//Создаем путь для будущего файла
$targetPath = $uploadsDir.$_FILES['cover']['name'];

//Проверяем наличие папки, если отсутствует - создаем
if (!file_exists($uploadsDir)
    mkdir($uploadsDir);

//Перемещаем файл
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, вероятно, нужен абсолютный путь к папке, а не относительно веб-корня:

```
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'],
    "/var/www/tanki_yrg/data/www/tankist10.hosting-test.org.ua/down/".basename($_FILES['cover']['name'])
);
```